# One employee can work in many hotels and one hotel can have many employees?

Tags: database, oracle, data-modeling

I need to create an intersecting table between the `Employees` and `Hotels` tables in my `Oracle` database:

one `Employee` can work in many `Hotels`, and one `Hotel` can have many `Employees`.

I think that I may be unnecessarily confusing myself though.

First, I began by first just creating a `FK` between the `Employee-Hotel-ID` column in the `Employees` table and the `Hotel-ID` column in the `Hotels` table.

But then I realized this does not allow many Employees to work at many Hotels.

Comment: OK - so you need 1) a table for employees, 2) a table for hotels and 3) a third, "WorksAt", table to represent your N::N relationship.

Comment: I second paulsm4:s comment. What you are looking for is a Junction table: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table

Just a tiny correction, it isn't a n:n relationship, but a m:n relationship.

A junction-table is usually done by having one table with just 2 primary-keys with FKs.

Comment: "m:n" is absolutely correct :)  And the "junction table" will typically contain other information, like shift# or pay rate (which might differ for different employees at different hotels).

Comment: Thank you for your replies. In that case, do I add the hotelID and employeeID as PK's to the WorksAt table, and add the foreign keys to the corresponding tables?

Comment: @paulsm4, would you be willing to create a simple join table as a formal answer? (since you were the one to answer)

Comment: @Lynette Shatto: "do I add the hotelID and employeeID as PK's" --- could you clarify this?

Comment: Above, Centril stated that the table should have 2 PK's with FK's.

Comment: @Lynette Shatto: oh I see now. It's probably just a bad wording.

Answer (score 3):

Using the dialect in en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table, we have:

```
CREATE TABLE Hotels (
    hotel_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    ...
)

CREATE TABLE Employees (
    employee_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    ...
)

-- This is the junction table.
CREATE TABLE WorksAt (
    hotel_id INTEGER REFERENCES Hotels (hotel_id),
    employee_id INTEGER REFERENCES Employees (employee_id),
    PRIMARY KEY (hotel_id, employee_id)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

1) As we discussed, you'll need

- a table for employees,
- a table for hotels and
- a third, "WorksAt", table to represent your M:N relationship (a "many to many" relationship).

2) The "WorksAt" table will have FK's for the EmployeeID and Hotel ID.  It might contain additional information specific to that particular relation, such as "shift#" for that employee at that hotel.

3) Here is a good discussion:

- http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/many-to-many.html

Comment: My pleasure: glad it helped.  Please feel free to "accept" the answer, if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Relational databases can't inherently handle many-to-many relationships. The standard approach is to create an intermediate table with a foreign key to both of the other tables.

Something like:

```
create table hotel_employee (
    hotel_id int,
    employee_id int
);
```

Such tables are often called *association* tables.

Comment: Thank you, should hotelID and employeeID in the intermediate table both be PK's? ... and then of course FK's corresponding to the other tables as you mentioned.